# Combining 2 tables with attachments i.e., multivalued fields in MS Access 13

Tags: mysql, ms-access, vba, union-all

I have two tables in MS Access that contain exactly three columns; a primary key, and two attachment fields which will be either MS Word or PDF documents.

These two tables contain a range of documents (A to P in the first table and Q to Z in the second table).

I need to perform a union query to get a resultant table with these three fields where the range is A to Z but I cannot, because of the multi-valued (attachment) fields that prevent a UNION query from being executed.

I cannot simply store all the data in one table to begin with because they are linked tables from another database that have to be combined in a different database.

Is there any way to have all three columns put into one table? I'm open to suggestions about changing the data type as well, but keep in mind that I could not use Hyperlinks because I am at a client terminal that only has acrobat reader and I do not have access to ACROBAT.EXE to open the PDF files (which is why I switched to attachments in the first place), and I cannot run Shell commands to find the Reader exe file either.

Edit:  I get an error message saying that 'myUsername' does not have access to open 'readerName'.exe. I tried this already with Acrobat Pro and Acrobat Reader.

Comment: That's a terrible reason not to use hyperlinks. `Application.FollowHyperlink "location_of_my_pdf"` will automatically open it in the default reader, be it acrobat or reader.exe, and there are many other ways to open PDFs as well. You can even open a PDF inside Access by using a webbrowser control.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth, I get an error message saying that <myUsername> does not have access to open <readerName>.exe 
I tried this already with Acrobat Pro and Acrobat Reader. This is why I switched to using Attachments in the first place.

About opening PDFs inside Access - could you please elaborate on how I could use the webbrowser control?

Comment: Well, the web browser control just displays a web page. You can embed pdf's inside web pages. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291813/recommended-way-to-embed-pdf-in-html) for how to embed pdfs in web pages. If you ask a specific question about that, I can try to come up with a specific answer.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Thank you, I will post a different question for that if I am not able to find substantial info online! :)